# How to save heap dump from Controller API?

Tags: jprofiler

I have tried everything. I tried the official TestProgram.java that is shipped with JProfiler, and also tried playing around with all available functions in the `Controller` class myself. I ensured that the JProfiler GUI was attached at jvm startup by using the agentpath VM parameter. I also tried connecting JProfiler later either with the GUI or with jpenable.

The result is always the same. No error is thrown. The produced `.jps` file contains telemetry data, cpu recording data (if I enabled CPU recordings) allocation data (if I enabled allocation recording), and even any thread dumps I triggered. But even though I call `Controller.triggerHeapDump`, and even though that runs without error, the heap dump data is never actually saved into the snapshot file.

The JProfiler version I am using is 13.0.7. I have tested this on both my local mac machine and a remote linux machine, and the result is the same. Heap data is never saved. When I go to the "Heap Walker" in the snapshot, it says "No snapshot has been taken".

I can take heap snapshots manually with the JProfiler GUI just fine. No problems there, and it will always save correctly into the snapshot if I clicked "Take snapshot" manually in the GUI.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, either with JProfiler 13 or 14. If I edit `api/samples/offline/build.gradle` and change the last line to ´args 'true'` (which enables the `triggerHeapDump` calls, I get snapshots with heapdumps in `$HOME/.jprofiler13/samples/build/offline/snapshots`